# What user credentials do I need to access Sharepoint Web Services

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, credentials

I currently have a web config file in a web service that is using the following code snippet so that it can access resources on Sharepoint

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="[domain admin]" password="[password]"/>
```

Clearly this situation is not a good idea and we are currently replacing this with the correct way of doing things. However, in the mean time we are creating a new domain user that is NOT the domain admin and using that as a stop gap. The domain admin was used as people were too lazy to determine the right security levels required and a domain admin will be guaranteed access to every resource.

My question is: What is the minimum level of security that this domain user requires in order to continue accessing the Sharepoint Web Service? What sort of things should I be thinking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What web service are you talking about exactly? SharePoint web services are permissions aware, just like any other module, so it is different if you want to say read items or create a site. You need to know first what you are trying to accomplish and then give the user the exact permissions to do that

Comment: Exactly what I was typing :-)

Comment: Thanks Vladi...sorry I know we have to avoid vague questions but I am brand new to SharePoint and probably don't really understand the question I am trying to ask.